# Can full text search thesauruses be used with SQL Server Azure?

Tags: full-text-search, azure-sql-database

I have a codebase that I'm trying to deploy against an Azure instance of SQL Server. The application makes use of full text search's thesauruses. That is, it makes queries using

`FORMSOF(THESAURUS, \"{0}\")`

According to [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/search/configure-and-manage-thesaurus-files-for-full-text-search), Azure SQL Server has thesauruses. But I've [read](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/efb6350a-5bdb-439a-a888-85feb8abddf9/azure-full-text-search-thesaurus-feature-enabled?forum=ssdsgetstarted) conflicting [things](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/full-text-search-is-now-available-for-preview-in-azure-sql-database/).

When I actually attempt this, I get the following error when the query tries to run:

`Both the thesaurus file for lcid '1033' and the global thesaurus could not be loaded`

I have checked that full text search is successfully installed on the server.

Is this even possible with Azure SQL Server?

Comment: Allow me time to find some help. I may not be able to find help until Monday. Thank you for your patience.

Comment: Thanks Alberto. We got it running for now on a SQL Server installed on a VM, but obviously this is not ideal. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Ok. I am trying to get confirmation first if the Thesaurus feature is supported or not on Azure SQL Database. Please allow me some time I just knocked some doors but is weekend.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The thesaurus feature of Full-Text Search is not supported on Azure SQL Database since the feature involves access to the file system and changes registry settings and files, and that is not allowed on Azure SQL Database. That is the answer I received from 2 Azure SQL Database managers today.

You may need to create an Azure VM with SQL Server installed to make use of the Thesaurus feature on Azure.

The article you shared with us will be updated to reflect the answer provided by SQL Azure team.

Thank you for your patience.